# Как заблокировать переход на страницу по URL

Tags: php

У меня есть форма входа на сайт и обрабатывается эта форма на странице `index2.php`. Я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог попасть на страницу `index2.php`, ТОЛЬКО после того как заполнит форму и нажмет кнопку. Также у него не должно быть возможности перейти на эту страницу по URL.

Comment: для apache есть [файл .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/), для nginx есть [rewrite_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html). Если "чистым PHP" - в начале файла `index2.php` проверяете наличие и значение $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php), если не соответствует URI формы - прекращаете обработку.

Comment: `Также у него не должно быть возможности перейти на эту страницу по URL.` имеете ввиду из адресной строки браузера? Если метод того URL формы будет не GET, а, например, POST (обычно так и происходит же), то просто ругаться сервером на неправильный метод

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko вам надо внимательнее читать вопрос.  файл .htaccess и  rewrite_module не имеют никакого отношения к проблемам автора.  Кроме того, наличие $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] не гарантируется, а так же этот заголовок легко подделывается.

Comment: Как тут многие правильно отмечают, **запретить** переходить на страницы нельзя (ну то есть можно, но тогда на нее вообще нельзя будет зайти). Но можно  сделать проверку и не показывать страницу, если орма не заполнена, а показывать ошибку или делать редирект

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант, отправлять форму входа методом POST, а в index2.php сделать отдачу страницы только в случае, если в параметрах `$_POST` присутствует какой-то элемент.

Например

```
if(isset($_POST['parameter'])) {
    echo $content;
}
```

В форме задайте атрибут `required` для обязательных полей

Comment: я бы наоборот сделал  if( ! isset($_POST['parameter'])) {
   exit;
} Код будет понятней.